# Html and CSS page will not scale with browser size

Tags: html, css

Here is my code for the HTML and CSS. For whatever reason, it will not properly scale down, regardless of my use of only %'s and vw's. The entree div and drink div are dynamically populated which has added a further challenge in the formatting.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/main.css">
<style>
  #percentageSize {
    width: 16%;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: -5%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    margin-left: -45%;
  }
  
  #percentageSize1 {
    width: 16%;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: -1%;
    margin-left: -400%;
  }
  
  .drinks {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 220%;
    margin-top: 2.5%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -53.5%;
  }
  
  #thumbs {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  .entree {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: -5%;
    margin-top: 7%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 34%;
  }
  
  h1 {
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .Joey {
    font-size: 3vw;
    margin-top: -18%;
  }
  
  h2 {
    text-align: right;
  }
  
  #continue {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    font-size: 1.1vw;
    padding: 1%;
  }
  
  #clear {
    padding: 1%;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    font-size: 1.1vw;
  }
  
  #add {
    padding: 1%;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    font-size: 1.1vw;
  }
  
  html {
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)), url(http://www.crossfitsofla.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/food.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
  }
  
  .header-right {
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top: -8%;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 2vw;
    color: black;
    margin-left: 65%;
    z-index: 1;
    font-family: Georgian
  }
  
  .buttons {
    margin-top: -6%;
  }
  
  .more {
    margin-top: 5%;
  }
  
  .Joey {
    color: PapayaWhip;
  }
</style>
<div class=stuff>
  <div class=Joey>
    <h1> Joey's Resturant
      <h1>
  </div>
  <div class="header-right">
    <a class="active" href="Entree Chooser.php" style="color: PapayaWhip; font-size: 2.3vw; font-family: Brush Script MT;">Order</a>
    <a href="email.php" style="color: PapayaWhip; font-size: 2.3vw; font-family:Brush Script MT;  ">Contact</a>
    <a href="real Home.html" style="color: PapayaWhip; font-size: 2.3vw; font-family: Brush Script MT;  ">Home</a>
    <a href="menue.php" style="color: PapayaWhip; font-size: 2.3vw; font-family: Brush Script MT;  ">Menue</a>

  </div>
  <div class=more>
    <h1> <span style="font-family:Georgian; font-size: 3.2vw;  color:white; "> Your Cart: </span>
      <h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class=buttons>
  <form action="handler2.php" method="post" name="formDemo">
    <input type='submit' id='clear' value='Clear' name='button2' />
    <input type='submit' id='add' value='Checkout' name='adder' />
    <input type='submit' id='continue' value='Continue Shopping' name='cancle' />
</div>


<br>
<br>

<body style="margin:75px;padding:75px">





  <h1> <span style='margin-left: -91%; font-size: 3vw; text-decoration: underline; font-family:Georgian; color:  white;'>  Entrees: </span>
    <h1>
      <h1> <span style='margin-left:7%; margin-top: -5%; text-decoration: underline;  position:absolute; font-size: 3vw; font-family:Georgian; color:  white;'>  Drinks: </span>
        <h1>
          <h1> <span style='font-family:Georgian; font-size: 3vw; color:white; position: absolute;  margin-left:8%; margin-top:-12%;'> 10456.71 </span>
            <h1>
              <div class='entree'>
                <h1> <span style='font-family:Georgian; font-size: 2vw; position:absolute;  margin-left: -50%; margin-top: 0%; color: PapayaWhip;'> Cheese Steak</span>
                  <h1>

                    <label>
         <img id='percentageSize' src='pics/steak.png' >  </img>
        </label>
                    <h1> <span style='font-family:Georgian; font-size: 1.5vw; margin-left: -50%; margin-top: -13%; position:absolute;  color: PapayaWhip;'>  Quantity: 1</span>
                      <h1><br>
                        <h1> <span style='font-family:Georgian; font-size: 2vw; position:absolute;  margin-left: -50%; margin-top: 0%; color: PapayaWhip;'> Breakfast Burrito</span>
                          <h1>

                            <label>
         <img id='percentageSize' src='pics/burrito.png' >  </img>
        </label>
                            <h1> <span style='font-family:Georgian; font-size: 1.5vw; margin-left: -50%; margin-top: -13%; position:absolute;  color: PapayaWhip;'>  Quantity: 1106</span>
                              <h1><br>
                                <div class='drinks'>
                                  <h1> <span style='font-family:Georgian; font-size: 2vw; position:absolute; margin-left: -224%; margin-top: 3.5%; color: PapayaWhip;'> Coke</span>
                                    <h1>

                                      <label>
         <img id='percentageSize1' src='pics/coke.png' >  </img>
        </label>
                                      <h1> <span style='font-family:Georgian; font-size: 1.5vw; margin-left: -224%; margin-top: -17.5%; position:absolute;  color: PapayaWhip;'>  Quantity: 1</span>
                                        <h1>
                                          <h1> <span style='font-family:Georgian; font-size: 2vw; position:absolute; margin-left: -224%; margin-top: 3.5%; color: PapayaWhip;'> Pepsi</span>
                                            <h1>

                                              <label>
         <img id='percentageSize1' src='pics/pepsi.png' >  </img>
        </label>
                                              <h1> <span style='font-family:Georgian; font-size: 1.5vw; margin-left: -224%; margin-top: -17.5%; position:absolute;  color: PapayaWhip;'>  Quantity: 700</span>
                                                <h1>
                                                  <h1> <span style='font-family:Georgian; font-size: 2vw; position:absolute; margin-left: -224%; margin-top: 3.5%; color: PapayaWhip;'> Red Bull</span>
                                                    <h1>

                                                      <label>
         <img id='percentageSize1' src='pics/redbull.png' >  </img>
        </label>
                                                      <h1> <span style='font-family:Georgian; font-size: 1.5vw; margin-left: -224%; margin-top: -17.5%; position:absolute;  color: PapayaWhip;'>  Quantity: 84</span>
                                                        <h1>
                                </div>
                                <div id='thumbs'></div> <span class='stretch'></span> </div>

</html>
```

Any help would be amazing. I am not sure what to do besides use %'s and vw's. Is it perhaps my use of div's?

Comment: For starters, your HTML is invalid. Try running it through [a validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) to fix the errors

Answer (score 2):

`VW` and `VH` stand for view-width and view-height respectively.  This means that your element that you have applied these to will maintain the same size across any scaling or device because it is a calculated as a percentage of the viewport.  For example, I could have a `<h1>` element that has the `font-size` of `10vw`.  This means that my `<h1>` will be 10% of the width of the device's viewport.

See:
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Values_and_units)
[w3](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css_units.asp)

```css
.pix {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

.v {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 20vh;
  background-color: purple;
  font-size: 5vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="pix">
<p>Pixels</p>
</div>

<div class="v">
<p>Viewport Based</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things wrong with your code. 
Firstly, you are not opening the `body` tag at the top, so I've moved that up (and put the inline style in the css). Second you aren't closing your tags correctly; none of the `h1` tags were closed, the closing `</form>` tag was missing, as was the closing `</body>` tag.
`<Img>` is a self-closing tag, it doesn't need a closing '' - just a '/>' at the end.

These are just a few pointers. You have a lot of inline style in your code that you may want to rethink. As an addendum, css is interpreted as it's written, so put the html/body css at the top of your stylesheet (it'll be applied faster for a start!)

Hope this helps.

p.s try and use position relative rather than absolute! Better for responsive design..

```css
html {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)), url(http://www.crossfitsofla.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/food.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

body {
  margin: 75px;
  padding: 75px;
}

#percentageSize {
  width: 16%;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: -5%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  margin-left: -45%;
}

#percentageSize1 {
  width: 16%;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: -1%;
  margin-left: -400%;
}

.drinks {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 220%;
  margin-top: 2.5%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -53.5%;
}

#thumbs {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.entree {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: -5%;
  margin-top: 7%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 34%;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.Joey {
  font-size: 3vw;
  margin-top: -18%;
  color: PapayaWhip;
}

h2 {
  text-align: right;
}

#continue {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  font-size: 1.1vw;
  padding: 1%;
}

#clear,
#add {
  padding: 1%;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  font-size: 1.1vw;
}

.header-right {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: -8%;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 2vw;
  color: black;
  margin-left: 65%;
  z-index: 1;
  font-family: Georgian;
}

.buttons {
  margin-top: -6%;
}

.more {
  margin-top: 5%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/main.css">
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="stuff">
    <div class="Joey">
      <h1> Joey's Resturant
      </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="header-right">
      <a class="active" href="Entree Chooser.php" style="color: PapayaWhip; font-size: 2.3vw; font-family: Brush Script MT;">Order</a>
      <a href="email.php" style="color: PapayaWhip; font-size: 2.3vw; font-family:Brush Script MT;  ">Contact</a>
      <a href="real Home.html" style="color: PapayaWhip; font-size: 2.3vw; font-family: Brush Script MT;  ">Home</a>
      <a href="menue.php" style="color: PapayaWhip; font-size: 2.3vw; font-family: Brush Script MT;  ">Menue</a>

    </div>
    <div class="more">
      <h1> <span style="font-family:Georgian; font-size: 3.2vw;  color:white; "> Your Cart: </span>
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <form action="handler2.php" method="post" name="formDemo">
      <input type='submit' id='clear' value='Clear' name='button2' />
      <input type='submit' id='add' value='Checkout' name='adder' />
      <input type='submit' id='continue' value='Continue Shopping' name='cancle' />
    </form>
  </div>


  <br>
  <br>

  <h1> <span style='margin-left: -91%; font-size: 3vw; text-decoration: underline; font-family:Georgian; color:  white;'>  Entrees: </span>
  </h1>
  <h1> <span style='margin-left:7%; margin-top: -5%; text-decoration: underline;  position:absolute; font-size: 3vw; font-family:Georgian; color:  white;'>  Drinks: </span>
  </h1>
  <h1> <span style='font-family:Georgian; font-size: 3vw; color:white; position: absolute;  margin-left:8%; margin-top:-12%;'> 10456.71 </span>
  </h1>
  <div class='entree'>
    <h1> <span style='font-family:Georgian; font-size: 2vw; position:absolute;  margin-left: -50%; margin-top: 0%; color: PapayaWhip;'> Cheese Steak</span>
    </h1>

    <label>
         <img id='percentageSize' src='pics/steak.png' /> 
        </label>
    <h1> <span style='font-family:Georgian; font-size: 1.5vw; margin-left: -50%; margin-top: -13%; position:absolute;  color: PapayaWhip;'>  Quantity: 1</span>
    </h1><br>
    <h1> <span style='font-family:Georgian; font-size: 2vw; position:absolute;  margin-left: -50%; margin-top: 0%; color: PapayaWhip;'> Breakfast Burrito</span>
    </h1>

    <label>
         <img id='percentageSize' src='pics/burrito.png'/>
        </label>
    <h1> <span style='font-family:Georgian; font-size: 1.5vw; margin-left: -50%; margin-top: -13%; position:absolute;  color: PapayaWhip;'>  Quantity: 1106</span>
    </h1><br>
    <div class='drinks'>
      <h1> <span style='font-family:Georgian; font-size: 2vw; position:absolute; margin-left: -224%; margin-top: 3.5%; color: PapayaWhip;'> Coke</span>
      </h1>

      <label>
         <img id='percentageSize1' src='pics/coke.png'/>
        </label>
      <h1> <span style='font-family:Georgian; font-size: 1.5vw; margin-left: -224%; margin-top: -17.5%; position:absolute;  color: PapayaWhip;'>  Quantity: 1</span>
      </h1>
      <h1> <span style='font-family:Georgian; font-size: 2vw; position:absolute; margin-left: -224%; margin-top: 3.5%; color: PapayaWhip;'> Pepsi</span>
      </h1>

      <label>
         <img id='percentageSize1' src='pics/pepsi.png' />
        </label>
      <h1> <span style='font-family:Georgian; font-size: 1.5vw; margin-left: -224%; margin-top: -17.5%; position:absolute;  color: PapayaWhip;'>  Quantity: 700</span>
      </h1>
      <h1> <span style='font-family:Georgian; font-size: 2vw; position:absolute; margin-left: -224%; margin-top: 3.5%; color: PapayaWhip;'> Red Bull</span>
      </h1>

      <label>
         <img id='percentageSize1' src='pics/redbull.png' />
        </label>
      <h1> <span style='font-family:Georgian; font-size: 1.5vw; margin-left: -224%; margin-top: -17.5%; position:absolute;  color: PapayaWhip;'>  Quantity: 84</span>
      </h1>
    </div>
    <div id='thumbs'></div> <span class='stretch'></span> </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use 'vh' for Height and 'vw' for width.

for example:

```
.content {
  height: 100vh; //it will make the height 100% of your browser screen
}
```